# Error PyQT5 plainTextEdit, AttributeError, how to fix?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Function in object:
file ParserWindow.py:

```
class Parser(object):
    def setupUi(self, ParserWindow):
          # code....
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet("font-family: \'Roboto Mono\';\n"
            "font-weight: 600;\n"
            "font-size: 14px;\n"
            "line-height: 24px;\n"
            "\n"
            "letter-spacing: 0.75px;\n"
            "\n"
            "color: #B5B5BD;")
        self.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")


  

    def addPlainText(self, text: str):
       self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(text)




class ParserWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Parser):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(ParserWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

File log.py (file for debug console):

```
from vendor.ParserWindow import Parser

parser = Parser()

def print_error(text: str):
    parser.addPlainText('[ERROR] {}'.format(text))

def print_info(text: str):
    parser.addPlainText('[INFO] {}'.format(text))

def print_warning(text: str):
    parser.addPlainText('[WARNING] {}'.format(text))
```

but when i run it gives out an error:

```
File "C:\Users\fazuq\Desktop\project\twitter\vendor\ParserWindow.py", line 581, in addPlainText
    self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText('{}'.format(text))
AttributeError: 'Parser' object has no attribute 'plainTextEdit'
```

hot to fix?
I use PyQt5

I want to make a function in the log.py file so that I can access other files to it and it adds text to PlainEditText

Comment: instead of `parser = Parser()` try `parser = ParserWindow()`

Comment: no errors, but no value is added to PlainText

Answer (score 0):

Try subcalssing QMainWindow directly.  Then leave your log.py the way you have it in your question.  I am assuming you also have already created the QApplication somewhere in your code prior to calling `Parser()`.

```
class ParserWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
          # code....
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.layoutWidget_6.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet("font-family: \'Roboto Mono\';\n"
            "font-weight: 600;\n"
            "font-size: 14px;\n"
            "line-height: 24px;\n"
            "\n"
            "letter-spacing: 0.75px;\n"
            "\n"
            "color: #B5B5BD;")
        self.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")

    def addPlainText(self, text: str):
       self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(text)
```

Comment: def retranslateUi(self, ParserWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(_translate("ParserWindow", "[INFO] Example\n"
            "[ERROR] Example"))

Comment: There is an error in part of the code that you didn't provide in the question so I can't really help you there.  In general you can just remove the retranslateUi method though without causing any harm.

Comment: I solved the problem with the method below, but perhaps there is a method more beautiful?)
`class ParserWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Parser):
    selfs = None
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        global selfs
        super(ParserWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        selfs = self
        self.setupUi(self)

    def getSelf():
        return selfs`

Comment: @WaySanders  Just make the same adjustments that I did in my example.... It should be roughly the same thing.  There is certainly no need for `selfs`